# Javascript: How to add two Stringarray - Elements to one String and without breaking lines

Tags: javascript

I want to print randomly a name with first name and surname. But between the first name and surname the lines were breaking.

The Code:

```
            var req1 = read("germannames.txt");
            var req2 = read("surnames.txt");
            var firstNames = req1.split(";");
            var surNames = req2.split(";");
            var randoms = "numbers:";

            var times= parseInt(document.getElementById('times').value);

         for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {

                var firstNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * firstNames.length +1);
                var surNumber = parseInt(Math.random() * surNames.length +1);

                var name = firstNames[firstNumber] + surNames[surNumber];

                document.getElementById('result').value += name;
        }
```

I read the text for the array:

```
        function read(fileName)
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/Bowixel/" + fileName, false);

            xhr.send(null);

            return xhr.responseText;
        }
```

The output:
[image: Output]

And how it should work:
[image: Result]

I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you share the array values?

Comment: You have not provided sufficient code for your the problem you want help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to remove the line feeding from the `firstNames[firstNumber]`, such as

```
var name = firstNames[firstNumber].replace(/^\n|\n$/g, '') + surNames[surNumber];
```

or try to use `trim()` if it is not a problem to remove the whitespace from both sides of a firstNames, like

```
var name = firstNames[firstNumber].trim()  + ' '+ surNames[surNumber];
```

Comment: I get the same result :/